# jquery trigger: how can I trigger the browse file in the input when I click on a text link?

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-forms-plugin, eventtrigger

Following up on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7131770/jquery-form-upload-plugin-how-to-reduce-it-to-one-click), I have another issuer - how can I trigger the browse file in the input when I click on a text link?

Basically I want to hide the form but it will be triggered when you click on the upload text link.

```
<a href="#" class="upload">upload</a>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm" style="display:none;">
  <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file[]" />
  <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

This is my working Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.upload').click(function(){
        $(this).trigger($('input[type=file]'));
        return false;
    });

    $('input[type=file]').change(function() {
        $('#myForm').ajaxSubmit({
               target: '#output'
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emulate a file upload click in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133058/emulate-a-file-upload-click-in-jquery)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't use `style="display:none;"` use `style="visibility:hidden;"`

and I changed trigger to click:

```
$('.upload').click(function(){
    $('input[type=file]').click();
    return false;
});
```

---

**Reasoning**:

The input fields will not be sent to the server with `display:none`, but will be with `visibility:hidden`.

Comment: The javascript worked for me to. But could you tell me why it worked and just a simple $("input[type=file]").click() wont ?

Comment: Thanks, although in my case the form element is visible. Still am unable to attach the direct "click" to it.

Answer (score 3):

why don't you use a label instead? then you could use the for attribute.

```
<style type="text/css">
  #file_upload {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
</style>
<a href="#" class="upload">
  <label for="file_upload">upload</label
</a>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myForm">
  <input id="file_upload" type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file[]" />
  <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Submit"/>
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Joe's method is correct. However, this solution will only work in some browsers. It works on Chrome and Firefox but not on Opera, Safari, or the Android Galaxy S built-in browser (tested on current versions as of June 23, 2012). Those browsers likely disable triggering the upload button via JS for security reasons.

I will update this post if I find a solution that works in all modern browsers

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? I have a similar issue and need to find something that works across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button>
  <label>
    select file
    <input type="file" style="visibility: hidden" file-handler>
  </label>
</button>
```

This should help you