# How to open an <input type="file"/> with a button click in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, button, input

How can I open an file input with a button click ? My code :

```
<Button variant="outlined">
      Choose Image
    </Button>
     <input
      type="file"
      id="input_file"
      accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png"
      style={{ display: 'none' }}
     />
```

Comment: To clarify: you want the browser to pop up windows explorer so the user chan a choose a file to upload when the button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, this i what i want

Answer (score 5):

## React >= 16.8 , using `useRef` hook

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const ref = useRef()
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    ref.current.click()
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Upload Image</button>
      <input ref={ref} type="file" />
    </>
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```

Comment: It works on my scenario perfectly: use ref to trigger file upload window from an image's click event, really thanks! (I wasted almost whole day on this)

Answer (score 0):

```
  const Open = () => { 
    document.getElementById('get_file').onclick = function() { 
      document.getElementById('input_file').click();}}

    <button id="get_file" variant="outlined" onClick={() => Open() } > Choose Image </button> 
    <input type="file" id="input_file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png" style={{ display: 'none' }} />
```

You have a answer here [How to link an input button to a file select window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10798761/how-to-link-an-input-button-to-a-file-select-window)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the post is old but my help may be useful to someone. You can use:

```
<Button variant='outlined' component='label'>
    <input
      type='file'
      hidden
      onChange={e => handleChange(e)}
    />
    Choose Image
</Button>
```